# How to gives access in API which user has roles name as SUB-ADMIN?

Tags: laravel, api

This is my UserController.php.I am using laravel passport for  API authentication

```
 public function login(Request $request){
        $login=$request->validate([
            'email'=>'required|string',
            'password'=>'required|string',
        ]);
        if(!Auth::attempt( $login )){
            return response(['message'=>"Invalid Login Credentials"]);
        }
        $accessToken=Auth::user()->createToken('authToken')->accessToken;
        return response(['user'=>Auth::user(),'access_token'=>$accessToken]);
    }
```

This is my routes/api.php

```
 Route::post('/user-login','UserController@login');
```

and i checked this URL in Postman  and result come like this

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user-login

{
    "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Admin User",
        "email": "admin@admin.com",
        "phone": "982356222",
        "roles": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Sub-Admin",
                "created_at": "2020-10-14 15:29:36",
                "updated_at": "2020-10-14 15:29:36",
                
            }
        ],
        
    },
    "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiIxIiwianRpIjoiYjY3MTE3ZjMxZmEzN2RhMGIyZGEzMmM0NDEzMDA2MDFkMTVhM2Y0ODdhNzFmNWIyMDcxNGZmNWY4M2MzYTVlNTFiNjQyMmJjODlmMzExOGIiLCJpYXQiOjE2MDU3MDQ3NDgsIm5iZiI6MTYwNTcwNDc0OCwiZXhwIjoxNjM3MjQwNzQ4LCJzdWIiOiIxIiwic2NvcGVzIjpbXX0.KunRT2KA8hI7c2lJW7e0nvJnWirgBrNgFAAyQq-PG6znHLS14-gcP-2rXWOfuGreW6N2yBxfu6AOg2BYOHNOg54qmXNJ6_fJRrOUpAjgCxEN60X8x_7lE2Gu0xXYhw0Oc5jCeCgtLdeh9DlHFIh2Wdhnd9lU4FMLcQl3q0TZt0Yf7FpQtv2-q2izOQlxV9QWO5R6mzlmg5feaqTUpx4repb2JpaCMAF47ZBn6ZYPDNcJTQJ6OdU5bzc3GWF3V97qJFS9OabMvA8bUmY8opirIAPb2Lqd9zmP06YMHOP0oT_qr0duQIWnCPQp3bGSf9lUlF0tKil3NR8YZtOhkjr9W6uQoe5n5AsZLJrfdeRbgwPsANink8NdWzfvHkBhmCEKJyiwUFQhTQAgrwc_uflv6XbJsIzVzsxihjIdl4b9Y-hmA-PnXzb108aeKH0Ja5DlP55Zk6AB3kiWx-Zf39aSvi0lQJDN6u2YuNhRnXdceFIzyGM2iV0fGqRqPKeA0FyUo4wBD3cX5_HlLHk7FPyltqWkMvoozc-JP8lmdROJypoPCDo0tOQHiD9pbnRu4hJnhoomQr0YZ5t9Z7AXtErEHRatshST5McSin8tGmYdTG4hxOY2yUZl7NTyloUVb_1vpDqh214hXm8KtykhlD-N98fX3XWjfZIXDBeD7qOeGdM"
}
```

But I want to give access to which user has roles name as Sub-Admin.If user roles has name Administrator or anything then give message as Invalid Login Credentials

Comment: you should associate scope to your token to grant special authoization to certain users https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#token-scopes

Answer (score 0):

I hope following code will help You

Apply middleware to check user role

```
// routes file
API.php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api', 'check.roles']], function() {
//your routes 
}


// http kenal.php Middleware registration 

 protected $routeMiddleware = [
'check.roles' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckRoles::class,
 ]

/// 
  public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        $user = auth('api')->user(); 
         //check user roles 
         if('condition' ){
            return $next($request);
        }else {
           return 'error';
         }
    }
```

Comment: Error Say Target class [App\Http\Middleware\CheckRoles] does not exist. in file

Comment: Do i have to make middleware CheckRoles.php ?

Comment: Yes, You need to create middleware.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware#defining-middleware